# how to move xlabel and ylabel to zeroaxis position in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, axis, axis-labels

In gnuplot, I use

```
set style line 11 lc rgb '#222222' lt 1;
set border 3 back ls 11;
set zeroaxis linetype 1 linecolor rgb '#222222'; 
set xtics axis; 
set ytics axis; 
set border 0;
set style line 12 lc rgb '#808080' lt 0 lw 1
set grid back ls 12
set xtics add ('' 0)
set ytics add ('' 0)
set xlabel 'x' font 'Times-Italic,14' 
set ylabel 'y' rotate by 0 font 'Times-Italic,14'
```

and this shifts the axis from the border to the 0 values of the axis. However, the xlabel and the ylabel remain at the border, giving them strange position. Is there a generic way of setting the axis labels to the position of the zero values of the axis?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use generic `set label` to position such labels. Then you can use `graph` and `first` coordinates to position the labels.

**y-label:** The starting point of the x-axis is at `graph 0, first 0` (left-most point of the plot and zero position in y-direction). Now, shift the label by an additional 1 character width to the left with `offset char -1,0` and right-align it:

```
set label 'y' at graph 0, first 0 offset char -1, char 0 right font 'Times-Italic,14'
```

**x-label:** The starting point of the y-axis is at `first 0, graph 0`. Shift the label by an additional 1 character width to the bottom and center it:

```
set label 'x' at first 0, graph 0 offset char 0, char -1 center font 'Times-Italic,14'
```

Note, that with this you must manually make enought space left and below the plot to accomodate the labels, e.g.

```
set lmargin 3
set bmargin 2
```

Full example:

```
reset
set zeroaxis linetype 1 linecolor rgb '#222222'
set xtics axis
set ytics axis
set border 0
set style line 12 lc rgb '#808080' lt 0 lw 1
set grid back ls 12
set xtics add ('' 0)
set ytics add ('' 0)
set label '{/:Italic x}' at first 0, graph 0 offset char 0, char -1 center font 'Times New Roman,14'
set label '{/:Italic y}' at graph 0, first 0 offset char -1, char 0 right font 'Times New Roman,14' 
set lmargin 3
set bmargin 2
plot x + 2
```

[image]

Note, that the syntax for getting italic labels was introduced only with version 5.